# Manipulating n different files and printing their maximum value to a newfile

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have 1000 data files-

```
F1.dat, F2.dat, ....., F1000.dat

F1.dat      F2.dat       F3.dat        F4.dat
2  3  3    3  4  3      3  4  4       2  3  4
3  4  5    2  6  3      4  5  3       4  5  6
5  6  3    2  1  4      2  3  4       0  9  3
2  3  3    1  0  9      1  1  4       3  4  3
.......    ......       ........      .......
```

I would like to calculate the maximum values of each corresponding entries from these 1000 files.

I mean the first entry (lets say, a11) of my new file will be

```
new file[a11] = Max(F1[a11], F2[a11], ..., F1000[a11])
```

Similarly all other entries. For the above example output is like-

```
newfile.dat
3   4    4 (i.e. max of 2 3 3 2, max of 3 4 4 3, max 3 3 4 4)
4   6    6
5   9    4
3   4    9
..........
```

I can't think how to do it?

Comment: Show sample data from your `.dat` file and your expected output.

Comment: I updated my question with some samples. Thank you @anubhava

Comment: Are all these file having similar 3x3 matrix like this?

Comment: All have same dimension. My data files are of ~1500000 x 10 size

Comment: Is using `awk` a requirement ? Why ? Do you have any code so far ?

Comment: sorry, I can't think of any algorithm in shell script, But I have one in fortran. Open file1.txt, open file2.txt,......, open file_n.txt
do j=1,10; do i=1,1500000; a[1]=f1(i,j); a[2]=f2(i,j);.......; a[n]=f_n(i,j);  new(i,j)=maxval(a)... It seems very manually and painful also.

Comment: You're welcome, it was really an interesting problem +1

Comment: @anubhava, Truly speaking, I have less knowledge in shell. I use fortran always. But when it comes with huge files, I failed in fortran. Now I will try for average.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `awk` using `FNR`:

```
awk '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      if ($i > a[FNR,i])
         a[FNR,i]=$i
      }
      rows=FNR;
      cols=NF
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=rows; i++) {
      for (j=1; j<=cols; j++)
         printf "%s ", a[i,j];
      print ""
   }
}' F*.dat
3 4 4
4 6 6
5 9 4
3 4 9
```